# Visual studio - buffer overrun

Tags: c++, arrays

Having this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>


double abs_length(int * ar)
{
    return (
        sqrt(pow(double(ar[0]), 2) + pow(double(ar[1]), 2))
        );
}

int ** correction(int size, int(*ar)[2], int refX, int refY)
{
    int **ar2 = new int*[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int x = abs(ar[i][0] - refX);
        int y = abs(ar[i][1] - refY);
        int vector[2] = { x,y };
        ar2[i] = vector;
    }
    return ar2;
}

double median(int size, int(*ar)[2], int refX, int refY)
{
    int **coordinates = correction(size, ar, refX, refY);
    double* lengths = new double(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        lengths[i] = abs_length(coordinates[i]);
    }
    sort(lengths, lengths + size);

    return  size % 2 == 0 ? (lengths[(size / 2) - 1] + lengths[size]) / 2 :
        lengths[(size / 2) - 1];
}
```

And for

```
lengths[i] = abs_length(coordinates[i]);
```

I am getting warning (which ends up with fatal error):

```
Buffer overrun while writing to 'lengths': the writable size is '1*8' bytes, but '16' bytes might be writen.
```

I do not understand it. Why could be 16 bytes written, when `double` is sizeof 8? 16 is address, but `abs_length` is returning double, no pointer. So where is bug?

Comment: My goodness that's some bad code. Do yourself a favor -- declare a struct with x and y elements, and use it instead of those two-element arrays. Your int(*_)[2]s are the source of your confusion.

Comment: `double* lengths = new double(size);` creates a memory location for `1` double with the value `size`. You probably want `double* lengths = new double[size];`.

Comment: You also leak `lengths` and `coordinates` on exit. Why not just use a `std::vector` and let the compiler manage memory for you?

Comment: @Sneftel it is bad. I wouldn't write it myself. It is just my university requirement

Comment: Maybe, your university course is bad: [Kate Gregory: Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) ;-)

Comment: @milanHrabos "_I wouldn't write it myself. It is just my university requirement_" But you **did** write it, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, but please read it again. I wouldn't. If I could, I would write it with classes or structs. But "make it in 2d array" was explicitly in my assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error here

```
int ** correction(int size, int(*ar)[2], int refX, int refY)
{
    int **ar2 = new int*[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int x = abs(ar[i][0] - refX);
        int y = abs(ar[i][1] - refY);
        int vector[2] = { x,y };
        ar2[i] = vector;
    }
    return ar2;
}
```

The lines

```
        int vector[2] = { x,y };
        ar2[i] = vector;
```

create a **local** array and stores a pointer to that array. The array is destroyed when you exit the body of the for loop, so you are storing a pointer to an object which has been destroyed.

This code would work

```
        int* vector = new int[2];
        vector[0] = x;
        vector[1] = y;
        ar2[i] = vector;
```

There may be other errors, far too many pointers in your code.

Comment: So how to fix it?

Comment: @milanHrabos See the edit, you need to allocate the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo:

```
new double(size)
```

allocates space for a single double with value `size`.

You probably meant:

```
new double[size]
```

which allocates space for an array of `size` doubles.

Comment: I corrected. But still getting the same error (overrun)

Comment: Still about writing to `lengths`? I find that hard to believe. Although `lengths[size]` at the end of the function is an invalid **read** access